# Is there a way to programmatically read the URLs of images from a Google Drive Public Folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, photo, drive

I am creating a website with nodejs and react and I wanted to display on my website some photos that I happen to store in google drive. Is there a way to do this without manually copying each photo's ID from google drive to build the link like this: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=..

I will have more folders and I wanted to make these folders public and use their URLs... and find a way to programmatically retrieve all the images from one folder at a time. Is this possible? I also need the images links to be permanent..or at least so that anyone on my website can see the images..

Comment: please check [google's api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

Comment: @IoanaC You can retrieve the list of all files from the public folder using [the files.list method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list). About your situation, I have one question. Are there several folders in the folder? Because the files.list method retrieves the files just under a folder. If there are several folders in the folder, it is required to prepare the script for retrieving all files.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for files with the files.list method of the Drive API.
For more info regarding API implementation in NodeJS you can visit official docs
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files